How can I center an item with altered height in Visjs Timeline?
So I want to shrink the height of the item "bubbles" or bars in the visjs timeline. However, when i alter the height to something like, say 10 px the item bar range shrinks down to the height I want. However, the bar is now not centered vertically in the row. It is slightly below center. No matter what css I have tried, I can't seem to get it vertically centered in the row. Any help would be great.
.vis-item{
height: 10px
}

When the height changes, I expected the visjs library to handle the centering vertically.Picture below for example, you can see its just below center.

